# Elements are not being removed from ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to remove elements that do not contain a specific string from an arrayList but with no luck. I am using the following code:

```
  ArrayList<String> classes = ClassesRetrieval.getYagoClasses();
  Iterator<String> it = classes.iterator();
   while(it.hasNext()){
     if(it.next().contains("yago")){
         it.remove();
     }
  }
  for(String i : classes){
      System.out.println(i);
  }
```

I also tried

```
      for(int i=0;i<classes.size();i++){
         if(!classes.get(i).contains("yago")){
         classes.remove(i);
          }
      }
      for(String i : classes){
          System.out.println(i);
      }
```

but with no luck..

Comment: Do you want to remove Strings that contain "yago" or don't contain "yago"?

Comment: What is your jdk version ?

Comment: @Eran that do not. Sorry, I corrected that!

Comment: What does that array actually look like? Is there perhaps a case-sensitivity issue? Also your second attempt will skip the second of any consecutive pairs of non-yago elements (you need to iterate in reverse order, or subtract 1 from `i` when you remove an element)

Comment: Are you sure that the string actually contains `yago` (and not `yAgo`, `Yago`, etc)? [Your first example works fine](http://ideone.com/iQpkm5)

Comment: @Dave The array is a list of URLs. if it was about Case sensitivity it would have removed all the elements!

Comment: @user1350162 no it wouldn't, because you missed the `!`. It would keep all the strings.

Comment: @Dave That's why I posted my initial comment. The first code attempt removes all the "yago"s and the second code attempt keeps just the "yago"s.

Comment: can you show us the result of System.out.println(classes) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested you first code on a list I created myself. It worked, but if you want to remove Strings that don't contain "yago", you are missing a `!`.

```
  ArrayList<String> classes = ClassesRetrieval.getYagoClasses();
  Iterator<String> it = classes.iterator();
   while(it.hasNext()){
     if(!it.next().contains("yago")){
         it.remove();
     }
  }
  for(String i : classes){
      System.out.println(i);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, I got you from the comments above! I dont know why I forgot that!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove '!' in your second code `if(!classes.get(i).contains("yago"))`, and i think it should work.
If it won't, give some base code of `ClassesRetrieval.getYagoClasses();`, please.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Yes, but i can't post comments.

Comment: you should still be careful posting comments as answers, even if you can't post them as comments; some people downvote them, and flags can be raised for it too. Until you've built-up some more rep (I don't think you need much more), it's best to stick to full answers (and in a case like this, there wasn't really enough information given by the OP for a proper answer yet)

Answer (score 0):

It might make since to iterate in reverse to avoid index problems.  Try something like this:

```
for(int i=classes.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
{
  //get a string from list
  String s = classes.get(i);
  if(!s.contains("yago"))
  {
    //if the string does not contain yago, remove it
    classes.remove(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: personally I prefer `for( int i = size; (i --) > 0; ) {` because the same construct works for unsigned numbers too. Also `contains` is clearer than `indexOf < 0`.

Comment: sorry I meant `!contains` (!)

Answer (score 0):

Using for loops to remove elements is really not recommended. Consider having two consecutive strings, both of which contain "yago". It will remove the first one, increment i and skip the second string (since it now has the index of the first string).

Try a while loop where you increment only if you don't remove the element (or, if you hate branching, reverse the for loop from greater to smaller).

As for your first example, right now it removes all those that do contain "yago". If you put a ! before the condition it should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your syntax/logic. However, it is possible that the condition

```
!classes.get(i).contains("yago")
```

Is not being met. To test whether this is true, I would print something if the condition yields true. For example:

```
  for(int i=0;i<classes.size();i++){
     if(!classes.get(i).contains("yago")){
     classes.remove(i);
     System.out.println("Condition Met");
      }
  }
```

You can even print the deleted element like this:

```
  for(int i=0;i<classes.size();i++){
     if(!classes.get(i).contains("yago")){

     System.out.println(classes.remove(i));
      }
  }
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The second piece of code you showed should work. Why are you using the negation (!) in your for loop?
I think that what you wanted is:

```
for(int i=0; i<classes.size(); i++){
    if(classes.get(i).contains("yago")){
        classes.remove(i);
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that when you remove an element from the list you change it's size. You could instead create an empty ArrayList and keep adding new elements to it if it does not obey the condition:

```
List<String> tmp = new ArrayList();
for(String token : classes){
    if(!token.contains("yago")){
        tmp.add(token);
    }
}

for(String i : tmp){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```